# Zig-Zag Lemma: Prove

Tags: homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I am trying to understand one step in Loring Tu's (Introduction to Manifolds) partial proof of the zig-zag lemma, showing that $H^k{C}$ is exact. See [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509511/the-zig-zag-lemma-in-cohomology), which doesn't ask this specific question.

[image]

### Question:

In $(*)$, why does $ji(a') = 0$?

Comment: That’s because $0 \to A_k \stackrel i \to B_k  \stackrel j\to C_k \to 0$ is exact, i.e. $\operatorname{im} i = \ker j$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the extremely obvious to me (but not too obvious for me to overlook..)!